# How do I prevent a RibbonControl from auto-hiding on form resize?

Tags: devexpress, ribbon-control

In DevExpress WinForms C#, I want to have the RibbonControl fill the form when I start the app, then expand the form according to the size of the UserControl depending on the ribbon button the user presses.

When I set the form size to the ribboncontrol's size, the ribbon control disappears - apparently this is a MS specification...

DevExpress support site refers to a [workaround](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S90862) in Delphi but I've been digging around in C# and can't find an equivalent workaround.